`router.push` not working in Next.js when clicking on submit
I'm working on a registration form in Next.js and I'm trying to redirect the user to an OTP verification page after successful registration. However, the router.push is not working as expected when the form is submitted. Here is my code:
"use client"
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import styles from "./registerForm.module.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import apiLinks from "@/api/api-links";
import { POST } from "@/api/api-calls";

const RegisterForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, getValues } = useForm();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await POST({ path: apiLinks['auth']['register'], body: data });
      router.push(`/otp/${data.email}`);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        // Handle HTTP errors
        console.error('HTTP Error:', error.response.data);
      } else {
        // Handle non-HTTP errors (e.g., network error)
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
      }
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ y: "5vh", opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.9, ease: "easeOut" }}
      style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
      className={styles.formContainer}
    >
      <h1 className={styles.text}>Register</h1>
      <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="E.g. John"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.firstName ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("firstName", {
            required: "First name is required",
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
              message: "First name should only contain letters",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.firstName && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.firstName.message}</span>
        )}

        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="E.g. Doe"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.lastName ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("lastName", {
            required: "Last name is required",
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
              message: "Last name should only contain letters",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.lastName && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.lastName.message}</span>
        )}

        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input
          type="tel"
          name="phoneNumber"
          placeholder="E.g. 123-456-7890"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.phoneNumber ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("phoneNumber", {
            required: "Phone number is required",
            pattern: {
              value: /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/,
              message: "Phone number must be in the format 123-456-7890",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.phoneNumber && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.phoneNumber.message}</span>
        )}

        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          placeholder="E.g parent@gmail.com"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.email ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("email", {
            required: "Email is required",
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/,
              message: "Invalid email address",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.email && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.email.message}</span>
        )}

        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.password ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("password", {
            required: "Password is required",
            minLength: {
              value: 8,
              message: "Password must be at least 8 characters",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.password && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.password.message}</span>
        )}

        <label>Repeat Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="repeatPassword"
          placeholder="Repeat Password"
          className={`${styles.input} ${errors.repeatPassword ? styles.errorInput : ""}`}
          {...register("repeatPassword", {
            required: "Repeat Password is required",
            validate: {
              matchesPassword: (value) =>
                value === getValues("password") || "Passwords do not match",
            },
          })}
        />
        {errors.repeatPassword && (
          <span className={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.repeatPassword.message}</span>
        )}

        <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
          {isLoading ? "Registering..." : "Register"}
        </button>
        <div className={styles.registerContainer}>
          Already have an account?
          <Link href="/login" className={styles.loginLink}>
            Login
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export default RegisterForm;

Details:

I'm using useRouter from next/navigation to navigate to the OTP page.
The registration form data is being sent via a POST request using a custom POST function.
On successful registration, I attempt to navigate to /otp/[email] using router.push(/otp/${data.email}).
However, the navigation is not happening after the form submission.

What I have checked:

The POST request is working correctly and returns a successful response.
The data.email contains the correct email address.
There are no errors in the console related to the navigation.

Question:
Why is router.push not working as expected? Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong in my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I suggest to import useRouter from "next/router" not "next/navigation"

Are you using the pages or app directory? - for reference see here
